# dualshock 4 not connecting to my ps4

Tags: ps4, controllers

Sorry for the broken english

hallo i have this small problem with my duelshock 4 controller 
it wont connect with my ps4 i tried to reset and it still doesn't work 
the licht doesn't blink if you push the ps4 button.

i tried to use it on my pc it works a little bit but it loses connection every 6 seconds

I don`t know if a part is broken because this controller is 3 years old

Comment: Have you tried putting new batteries in the controller? It seems simple but it's often overlooked

Answer (score -1):

Try and factory reset on the controller.

video showing you how here.